# Retrieve all phone contacts regardless their group

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts, google-contacts-api

I'm having a problem retrieving all phone contacts.

when using the following selection clause, I'm not getting contacts that not been saved in association to group (such google specific account group):

```
    final static String SELECTION = (Utils.hasHoneycomb()
            ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
            : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME) + "<>''" + " AND " + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1";

...
... 

// onCreateLoader() code:
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Contacts.CONTENT_URI, ContactsQuery.PROJECTION,
            ContactsQuery.SELECTION, null, ContactsQuery.SORT_ORDER);
```

got this snippet from one of the Google tutorials or demo projects.

following the documentation, I realized that `Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1"`  causing the filtering of contacts that not belong to any group, so I simply removed this condition expecting to get also the contacts that don't belongs to any group:

```
final static String SELECTION = (Utils.hasHoneycomb()
            ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
            : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME) + "<>''";
```

after using this SELECTION clause - I got all the contacts includes the ones that not belongs to any group, but now **I got duplication of all the contacts that does belongs to a group**.

please help me understand how to perform query that returns all contacts without duplication

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri contactUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
                Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver()
                        .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                String number = cursor.getString(column);

                int column1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String name = cursor.getString(column1);
```

Comment: I don't understand.  the snippets you providing demonstrats how to receive a specific contact details, and not all contacts.

Comment: This snippets gets me all the contacts name as well as the number.Sorry didn't get what you want to achieve